# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
app.post('/students/search', (req,res) => {
 fs.readFile('./db/students.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let studentsArr = JSON.parse(data);
    let reqName = req.query.name;
    console.log(reqName);
    let result;
    studentsArr.filter(el =>{
        let lowerCaseName =  el.name.toLowerCase();
        result = lowerCaseName.match(reqName);
        if(result){
            res.send(el);
        }
    });
 });
```

});

Столкнулся с одной проблемой, отправляю запрос на сервер, чтоб вывел мне все найденных студентов по имени, но выводит вот такую ошибку:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: Я так подозреваю, что нельзя делать несколько `res.send`. Соберите всех нужных студентов в массив и отправьте разово.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка кроется здесь:

```
studentsArr.filter(el =>{
    let lowerCaseName =  el.name.toLowerCase();
    result = lowerCaseName.match(reqName);
    if (result) {
        res.send(el);  // вот здесь
    }
});
```

Коллбэк, переданный в функцию `filter`, будет вызван для каждого элемента массива, а значит, если более одного объекта удовлетворят вашим условиям, то `res.send` будет вызван несколько раз (и вылетит ошибка, которая вылетела у вас, потому что отправить ответ можно только раз).

Попробуйте вынести `res.send` из скоупа функции `filter`:

```
let studentsAfterFilterList = studentsArr.filter(el =>{
    let lowerCaseName =  el.name.toLowerCase();
    return lowerCaseName.match(reqName);
});

res.send({ result: studentsAfterFilterList }
```

Тогда клиент, сделавший запрос, получит такой ответ:

```
{
    result: [
        // найденные объекты
    ]
}
```